# PHP How to replace string literals using a value from an array?

Tags: php, string, literals

I'm not sure if it's the proper title to use...

Here is my question.

I have stored table field names from a database in an array, and created a string like following

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $str.="<td>{$data[key][field]}</td>";
}
```

And I have stored the data from the table in a different array which is of the form

```
$data=array(array('name'=>"name 1",'address'=>"Address One"),array('name'=>"Name 2",'address'=>"Address two"),array('name'=>"Name 3",'address'=>"address three"),array('name'=>"test",'address'=>"test one"));
```

Now I have done the following

```
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
foreach ($data as $key => $souceStr) {
    ?>
    <tr>
       <?=$str?>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>
```

My aim is to replace the string that i have created from the first array with the values from the second array. I have seen coding in CMS like joomla where they replace '{somename}' with a value I want to do the same here.

=================================================

I'm sorry My question was not clear. But i got what i was looking for. Here is the code

```
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="1">    
<tr>
    <?
    foreach ($header as $val) {
        ?>
        <th><?= $val ?></th>
        <?
    }       
    ?>
</tr>
<?
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $str.='<td>$souceStr['.$field.']</td>';
}  
foreach ($data as $key => $souceStr) {
    eval("\$eval_str = \"$str\";");
    ?>
    <tr>            
       <?php echo $eval_str; ?>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>
```

The idea was to print a html table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I completely understand what your question is, but what if you simply made a string from the second array just like you did from the first one? the result wold be the same, right?